# jar unable to locate audio files

Tags: java, audio, intellij-idea, jar, lwjgl

So I'm writing a program in Java that must be able to play wav files. It works perfectly when run from within Intellij, but when I run it from the jar it crashes immediately when it tries to retrieve the sound files and returns this error:

```
Unable to create from inputstream, Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Here is the code that I'm using to retrieve the sound files:

```
protected int loadSound(String file) {

    int data = AL10.alGenBuffers(); //Create new buffer object
    buffers.add(data); //Store buffer ID in array list
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream filePath = loader.getResourceAsStream("/res/sound/" + file);
    WaveData wavFile = WaveData.create(new BufferedInputStream(filePath)); //Retrieve wav file
    AL10.alBufferData(data, wavFile.format, wavFile.data, wavFile.samplerate); //Store wav file data and properties in buffer object
    wavFile.dispose(); //Discard wav file from stored memory

    return data; //Return buffer ID
}
```

I cannot understand why this does not work when run from the jar, since when I look inside the jar file I can see that the res folder is indeed inside of it. What's stranger still is that I'm using more or less identical code to retrieve a text file in another part of the program and have been able to confirm that this is working correctly when run inside the IDE and from the jar. That code is as follows:

```
ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream mapPath = loader.getResourceAsStream("dat/maps/" + mapName);
```

I know similar questions have been asked here many times before, but I have not had any success with the solutions I found to those questions. I am pretty sure it's something to do with the files not being packaged correctly, but I cannot say how it should be done.

Here is the complete stack trace:

```
C:\Users\Jack>java -jar C:\Users\Jack\IdeaProjects\ProjectBlackSpace\out\artifacts\ProjectBlackSpace_jar\ProjectBlackSpace.jar
OpenALC10: true
OpenALC11: true
caps.ALC_EXT_EFX = true

Num HRTF specifiers = 2: true
Sample rate: default-44100
HRTF enabled: true
HRTF state: 0x3

OpenGL version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.81
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
        a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
        b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
Unable to create from inputstream, Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Sounds.loadSound(Sounds.java:22)
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Player.init(Player.java:94)
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Game.init(Game.java:72)
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.run(Main.java:159)
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.init(Main.java:82)
        at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.main(Main.java:195)
AL lib: (EE) alc_cleanup: 1 device not closed
```

When running the program with `-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true` The results when running from the command line are no different, but when run from within the IDE it provides some more information:

```
[LWJGL] Version: 3.0.0 build 90
[LWJGL]      OS: Windows 10 v10.0
[LWJGL]     JRE: 1.8.0_60 amd64
[LWJGL]     JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM v25.60-b23 by Oracle Corporation
[LWJGL] Loading library (system): lwjgl
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: libs\lwjgl.dll
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil accessor: MemoryAccessorUnsafe
[LWJGL] Loading library: OpenAL
[LWJGL] ThreadLocalUtil state: UnsafeState
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: libs\OpenAL.dll
OpenALC10: true
OpenALC11: true
caps.ALC_EXT_EFX = true

Num HRTF specifiers = 2: true
Sample rate: default-44100
HRTF enabled: true
HRTF state: 0x3
[LWJGL] Loading library: glfw
[LWJGL]     Loaded from java.library.path: libs\glfw.dll
[LWJGL] Loading library: opengl32
[LWJGL]     opengl32.dll not found in java.library.path=libs/
[LWJGL]     Loaded from system paths

OpenGL version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.81
[LWJGL] Loading library: jemalloc
[LWJGL]     jemalloc.dll not found in java.library.path=libs/
[LWJGL]     jemalloc.dll not found in system paths
[LWJGL]     Using SharedLibraryLoader...
java.lang.RuntimeException:     Failed to extract jemalloc library
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:65)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNative(Library.java:139)
    at org.lwjgl.system.jemalloc.JEmalloc.<clinit>(JEmalloc.java:37)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryManage.getInstance(MemoryManage.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil$LazyInit.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:76)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.nmemAlloc(MemoryUtil.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memAlloc(MemoryUtil.java:180)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memUTF8(MemoryUtil.java:1530)
    at org.lwjgl.system.APIUtil.apiArrayi(APIUtil.java:430)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(GL20.java:425)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Shaders.init(Shaders.java:29)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.run(Main.java:123)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.init(Main.java:82)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.main(Main.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to locate resource: jemalloc.dll
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.java:80)
    at org.lwjgl.system.SharedLibraryLoader.load(SharedLibraryLoader.java:63)
    ... 20 more
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
    b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: jemalloc.dll
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNativeRelative(Library.java:177)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadNative(Library.java:134)
    at org.lwjgl.system.jemalloc.JEmalloc.<clinit>(JEmalloc.java:37)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryManage.getInstance(MemoryManage.java:36)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil$LazyInit.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:76)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.nmemAlloc(MemoryUtil.java:162)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memAlloc(MemoryUtil.java:180)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.memUTF8(MemoryUtil.java:1530)
    at org.lwjgl.system.APIUtil.apiArrayi(APIUtil.java:430)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glShaderSource(GL20.java:425)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Shaders.init(Shaders.java:29)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.run(Main.java:123)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.init(Main.java:82)
    at projectBlackSpaceApp.Main.main(Main.java:195)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
[LWJGL] [MemoryAllocator] Failed to load the jemalloc library.
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil allocator: StdlibAllocator
```

Adding the `jemalloc.dll` to the library directory does stop the runtime exception from happening, but it doesn't seem to have any other effect for better or worse.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Adding the jemalloc.dll to the library directory does stop the runtime exception from happening, but it doesn't seem to have any other effect for better or worse.` What do you mean???? No errors in the stacktrace but no audio coming?

Comment: Yes, both of those things.

Comment: Oh but I should mention that I am still getting the `Unable to create from inputstream, Stream closed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException` error when the program tries to retrieve the first sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the difference between: `"/res/sound/"` and `"dat/maps/"`.  That is the `/`

**UPDATE**

From the stacktrace it looks like a shared library is expected to be present. Please do what is suggested:

> Possible solutions:
>           a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
>           b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.

Comment: Yes that is true, but even if I remove the leading slash it is the same problem. Runs within the IDE, but crashes when run from the jar. In the latter case if I open with a leading slash it crashes in both scenarios.

Comment: are you sure the audio file is included into the jar under the `res/sound` directory? And can you post the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Yes I am sure of that, if I look inside of the jar file using 7-zip the `res/sound` directory is indeed there. I've added the complete stack trace to my answer.

Comment: Ok, the directory is there but does the file you are trying to access exist also inside this directory in the jar file? Please edit your question and attach the stacktrace

Comment: Yes all the wav files are in their expected directories within the `res/sound` directory.

Comment: From the stacktrace `[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
        a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
        b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.` looks like you are missing a required shared library. if you run the jar with the option `-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true` suggested what do you get?

Comment: Read also here, most probably you need the .so library: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38934607/lwjgl-failed-to-load-a-library

Comment: I see what you mean, as far as I can tell though I have all the required dlls in the libs folder which is being pointed to in the VM arguement `-Djava.library.path=libs/`. I will paste the results of running the program with `-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true` into my answer. I am running my program on windows so I don't need to link to the .so libraries as they are for Linux only. I have  `glfw.dll`, `glfw32.dll`, `lwjgl.dll`, `lwjgl32.dll`, `OpenAL.dll`, `OpenAL32.dll` in my libs directory.

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Failed to locate library: jemalloc.dll` You also need this dll

Comment: Yes you're quite right, I have now added `jemalloc.dll` to the libs directory. Now when I run from the command line there are no reported errors at all, the program simply crashes without giving any feedback. Thank you for helping me through this by the way :)

Comment: Check the "/" then in the path and try to find out at which line it crashes.

Comment: Removing the leading "/" Doesn't appear to make any difference :(

Comment: ok try to debug it the "traditional" way. Put some `system.out.println`s  after each line in your `loadSound` method and see which of them print out to find out where it crashes.

Comment: After doing things the "traditional" way as you suggested, it appears that the program closes immediately after it attempts to load the first sound and does not continue beyond that point. The line that attempts to load this first sound is as follows: `spawnSound = sounds.loadSound("player/spawn.wav");`. This sound is indeed inside the jar at the correct location.

Comment: Oh my god, I just released why it is not working, I have to write the .wav in all caps like this: ".WAV". Thank you so much for your help, sorry for sending you on this wild goose chase. :D

Comment: Indeed, the contents of a jar file do not belong to the filesystem (if it were, since you are on windows case sensitivity is not an issue). So case sensitivity matters inside the jar file. But apart from this you also had the .dll problems surfaced from the stacktrace inspection. It would still not work even if you provided the correct case sensitivity because you lacked the libraries.

Comment: Good point, I've edited my answer to reference that as well. Thanks again for all your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was twofold. Firstly I had not included an essential .dll file in my libs directory, secondly I was ending the file name with the extension ".wav" when I should have been using ".WAV". (facepalm)